# How to create a website using free domain and microsoft expression web 4

Tags: html, subdomain, google-web-designer

I have created a website through Microsoft expression web 4.
(Used CSS and various html that hyperlinks through each html)

Also, I created a free domain using free website domain sources.

But I do not know how to connect these two. Could anyone help?

Comment: Why is this tagged google-web-designer if you used expression web 4?

Comment: We can't tell you how your hosting service works. You haven't even told us which one you are using. Consult their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any free hosting out there.

If you only want to store your static pages, you can use static paging service like https://pages.github.com (It's free).

There's a complete tutorial for it, you just have to Google it.